Why is "に" used in 霧雨に霞み?
The character is watching someone run away in the rain and the narrator says this:

霧雨に霞み、実際よりも遠くに見える。

I know "実際よりも遠くに見える。" means "He appears more far than he is" but what does "霧雨に霞み" provide here? Why is に used?

霞む is an intransitive verb meaning "to get blurry", and the に after 霧雨 is a cause/trigger marker ("by ～" or "due to ～"). It's the same に as in 病に倒れる, 風に揺れる, 大きな音に驚く, etc.

霧雨に霞み、実際よりも遠くに見える。
Blurred by the drizzle, [he] looks farther away than [he] actually is.

